# Why is my execution being stopped after printing a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* link;
};
typedef struct node NODE;
typedef struct node HEAD;

void main()
{
    NODE *head;

    NODE *node1;
    node1 = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    node1->data = 6;
    node1->link = head;
    head = node1;

    NODE *node2;
    node2 = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    node2->data = 7;
    node2->link = head;
    head = node2;
    NODE *ptr = head;
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d->",ptr->data);  //printing of current node's data.
        ptr = ptr->link;           //<------here execution is being halted after printing 5 and 6

        if(ptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("NULL");
        }
        
    }
}
```

The output is

```
7->6->
```

But i need expected output as

```
7->6->NULL
```

Can you please look into the code and correct my code if necessary and also please explain why my execution is being halted after printing data and not executing the printf("NULL") statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```c
node1->link = head;
```

At here, the pointer `head` is still **uninitialized**, that is neither a block of memory nor `NULL`. So the linked-list is actually looking like `7 -> 6 -> ???`. Since its not `NULL`, it doesn't satisfy the `ptr == NULL` comparison though satisfies `ptr != NULL`, kept running the loop but couldn't access the members' data (since there isn't a thing to access), so it halted.

Try initializing `struct node *head = NULL`.

Comment: Thank you for answer it works!:) wait so head = NULL is same as head pointing to NULL right?.

Comment: @Aryan yup I would say so. btw people use loop to create new node and connect it onto the list, not declaring all of 'em.

Comment: i got it and also another question don't mind me but when struct node* head = struct node *node1 what is head storing actually? is it the address?

Comment: pointers are also a value, like `0x28ef`, just the value marks an actual memory location. How do you think the following code work? `int a = 10; int b = a;`

Comment: b must be 10   because b is storing a's value

Comment: And the `head`  `node1` relationship is the same.

Comment: what about struct node head = struct node node;